# Is it possible to use column tuples in a where condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Consider a table with a composite primary key:

```
create table T (
    C1 int not null,
    C2 int not null,
    ...
    primary key (C1, C2)
)
```

and the problem of retrieving the rows greater than a certain primary key tuple:

```
select * from T where (C1, C2) > (10, 100)
```

The pseudo-syntax above is invalid on MSSQL and Oracle. It can be implemented as:

```
select * from T where (C1 = 10 and C2 > 100) or (C1 > 10)
```

The more columns the PK has, the uglier this gets. Is there any elegant way of doing this (MSSQL and Oracle)?

Also, it's important to take advantage of the unique index on (C1, C2). I wouldn't want to concatenate the columns in a string to simulate the tuple and then end up with a table scan.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you think this is ugly.  You are either adding more columns to your where clause, or you're adding more columns to the composite key. As long as you start with the left-most columns in your pk, the index should be used.  I think that if it's a covering index, you can skip columns (but could be wrong).

Comment: To see the ugliness, imagine how the condition looks for 10 columns. If tuples were supported, it would just be (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10) > (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?). I'll let you fill in the other one, it's O(N^2) ... Also, in my real case this SQL is dynamic, so the complexity to generate the explicit conditions is higher.

Comment: I think this question belongs more to dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The reason why your pseudo code doesn't work and can never work is that they could hardly implement this feature suitable for every purpose. For you (10,200) is bigger than (9,900), for others it isn't. If for instance these were coordinates then (10,200) would be closer to (0,0) than (9,900) and hence regarded the smaller value.

Comment: I would disagree here. An index lookup uses exactly this kind of tuple comparison. All they need to do is add the syntax for it. The ordering  is well defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

afair there is no elegant and fast way to do it, if you really have only 2 int columns - try to combine them into one bigint, but for more - you will need to produce such ugly where condition, good news - it will use primary key index and will work pretty fast

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a comparision of glued keys:

```
'11000' > '10100'
'10101' > '10100'
'10099' < '10100'
'09999' < '10100'
```

To achieve this you need a virtual column. In Oracle you would just build a functional index, in SQL Server you would create a computed column first and build the index on that.

You could write a deterministic (!) glue function to glue your keys together and use this:

```
alter table T add column GluedKeys as GlueTKeys(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5);

create index IndexGluedTKeys on T(GluedKeys);

select * from T where GluedKeys > GlueTKeys(?,?,?,?,?);
```

Be aware of how long the single keys can be. Don't glue 10 + 100 to 10100 and 20 + 10 to 2010, but rather 20 + 10 to 20010.

Comment: I know this doesn't comply with your request that the primary key index shall be used. It does use an index though and the sql looks neat.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments to your question you remark that in your real case the SQL is dynamic. So why even bother? You can easily create a statement for n keys in a loop producing "... (c1 > 10) or (c1 = 10 and c2 > 100) or (c1 = 10 and c2 = 100 and c3 > ..." .

That may and may not use your pk index. I daresay with so many ors it is likely not to be used. You would have to force it then:

```
select * 
from T with (index(pk_t))
where ...
```

Comment: I tested it and the index was actually used. That was a very pleasant surprise.